# django template tag shorten string

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following in a template -

```
<tes:productiondate>{% now "Y-m-d" %}T{% now "H:i:s" %}-{{{% now "u" %}|truncatechars:4}}</tes:productiondate>
```

It's giving me an error

```
Could not parse some characters: |{% now "u" %}||truncatechars:4
```

`{% now "u" %}` does display correctly the problem is that by default it displays 6 characters and I only want it to display 4 characters.

I'm realizing that truncatechars it's the right way to do it because I don't want the "..." so how do I go about shortening the string of 6 characters to be only 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply a filter to template tag's output.  In trunk version of django `{% now %}` tag can save formatted time to variable:

```
{% now "u" as msec %}{{ msec|truncatechars:4 }}
```

But in the current stable django (1.7.2) the `as` keyword is not supported.

So you have to write [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/). It is easy:

```
import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def microseconds(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%f')[:4]
```